# Array element additions in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this array:

```
a1 = [1,2,3,4]
```

I want to generate this array from `a1`:

```
a2 = [3, 5, 7]
```

The formula is `[a1[0] + a1[1], a1[1] + a1[2], ...]`.

What is the Ruby way to do this?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can do this as below:

```
a1 = [1,2,3,4]
a2 = a1.each_cons(2).map{ |a| a.inject(:+) } #=> [3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: The second line could also be `a2 = a1.each_cons(2).map{ |a,b| a + b }` which I find a bit easier to read.